# C++ Components based class

Tags: c++

Hi,

I'm writing a component based class with a container, but after thinking of many different approaches, I can't find one that follows really what I want.

Here is an example of the general idea :

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/38394964.png/]

And the code I already wrote :

```
// Abstract class Component
class Component
{
public :
    virtual ~Component() = 0;
    virtual int GetResult() = 0;
};


class AddComponent : Component
{
public :
    int GetResult() { return input1->GetResult() + input2->GetResult(); }

    void SetInput1(Component* c) { input1 = c; }
    void SetInput2(Component* c) { input2 = c; }

private :
    Component* input1;
    Component* input2;
};

class ConstComponent : Component
{
public :
    int GetResult() { return value; }

    void SetValue(int x) { value = x; }

private :
    int value;
};

class SignComponent : Component
{
public :
    int GetResult() { return sign(input->GetResult()); }

    void SetInput(Component* c) { input = c; }

private :
    Component* input;
};


class Container
{
public :
    Container();
    ~Container();

    void SetRootComponent(Component* c) { rootComponent = c; }

    int GetResult() { return rootComponent->GetResult(); }

    AddComponent* AddComponentAdd();
    ConstComponent* ConstComponentAdd();
    SignComponent* SignComponentAdd();

private :
    Component* rootComponent;
    std::vector<Component*> components;
};


void main(void)
{
    // Create container
    Container container = Container();

    // Create components
    SignComponent*    cSign = container.AddComponentSign();
    AddComponent*      cAdd = container.AddComponentAdd();
    ConstComponent* cConst1 = container.AddComponentConst();
    ConstComponent* cConst2 = container.AddComponentConst();

    // Link components
    cSign->SetInput(cAdd);
    cAdd->SetInput1(cConst1);
    cAdd->SetInput2(cConst2);
    cConst1->SetValue(-5);
    cConst2->SetValue(3);

    // Set root component for container
    container.SetRootComponent(cSign);

    // Compute
    int result = container.GetResult();
}
```

This doesn't even compile, because of the cast of "XComponent" to "Component", which is abstract. I'm pretty sure there is a much better (and simpler ?) way to do it anyway, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I don't see the XComponent you are asking about...

Comment: @JerryCoffin, the link you posted is broken

Comment: This strikes me as a particularly severe case of the [xy problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @steffen : Sorry if I wasn't explicit, the cast I talked about is in AddComponentAdd(), ConstComponentAd(),..., where I add the special type component to the generic component list.

Comment: @JerryCoffin : Indeed, I have a sort of two-in-one problem (the cast problem and the general architecture problem), but it is rather the architecture (Am I doing right ?) that bothers me

Comment: @Jack: Unfortunately, without knowing what you're really trying to accomplish, it's hard to advise how to accomplish it well. At least right off, however, what you're showing looks to me like it causes as many problems as it solves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default inheritance for `class` is `private`:

```
class ConstComponent : Component
```

For all subclasses of `Component` you need `public` inheritance:

```
class ConstComponent : public Component
```

if you are attempting to insert `new` instances of the subclasses into the `std::vector<Component*>` (which I *think* you are).
`private` inheritance is not an `is-a` relationship, but is a `has-a` relationship. See [How are "private inheritance" and "composition" similar?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/priv-inherit-like-compos.html) .

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I feel a little stupid not having seen this. :-)
Any idea about the "pertinence" of my architecture against the type of data I'm manipulating ?