# Adding unlimited number of classes as a member og GameObect C++

Tags: c++, game-engine

Thanks for reading!

### Problem Itself

So the question is **Is there any simple specific way provided by C++  to add unlimited number of unspecified classes as a members**
 or have I play with vectors ;)
They must be:

- Able to add when the program is running
- Able to add many different classes that even doesn't exist now, so I can't 
  use std::optional because I will die with every code change.
- Able to remove also during program work.

I found something that can be similar [C++ Components based class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526297/c-components-based-class)
but this can't help me because I neeed flexibile code without prdefining what classes can be memeber of Game Object

---

This is my first question on stack overflow so pleas be patient ;) I'll be very glad for any kind of help.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: As it stands now it is unclear what the question is. SO is about specific programming Q&A, not about design and architecture. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I thought that is some specific way to solve that kind of problem (maybe even a partr of the language) I didn't know it's architecture problem

Comment: Templates are part of the language (but how useful they are for you depends on what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're heading the right way. You see, games don't usually have a lot of dynamic stuff. Usually, you might want to load a level in memory where it stays until it's completed by player. When it does, you may clean all the game objects and load a next level. Open world games are more complicated and you might have to load and unload adjacent areas on fly when developing one. Also, games require lots of CPU speed, so when you create lots of dynamic stuff it leads to fragmented spaghetti structure of your memory and lots of cache misses. You don't want that. Dynamic classes will require trampoline code to connect your functions together and it'll lead to another performance loss. Solve your problems one by one. You don't have that much classes to have a need for another CORBA or DCOM yet. I guess, you'll never have. Linux core is monolithic, for instance.

IMHO C++ isn't any good for making binary interfaces.

If you want to make a plugin API, you might list some predefined directory for *.dll files, load each DLL file and call some function from it, something like "LoadGameEnginePlugin". Valid plugin will return a structure describing its functionality and pointers to functions implementing one. After that, you call these functions via pointers.

If you want to extend your GameObject's functionality indefinitely, you may look to [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [MultiMethod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) design patterns.

Comment: Thanks You see I'm not trying to make a game but a Engine (as a hobbyst) and I want to add once created components to many GameObject and also add custom user classes which also need to be added. So classes will be added not during the game but during the game making.